# Why does reading from "git --version" show up on a different channel from "python --version" via subprocess?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

Can someone please explain why the output of the following command("python --version") is going to standard error instead of standard output?

```
import shlex, subprocess

cmd = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("git --version"), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)

std_out, std_err = cmd.communicate()

print("std_out: {}".format(std_out))
print("std_err: {}".format(std_err))

cmd = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("python --version"), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)

std_out, std_err = cmd.communicate()

print("std_out: {}".format(std_out))
print("std_err: {}".format(std_err))
```

This is what gets printed:

```
std_out: git version 2.19.2

std_err: 
std_out: 
std_err: Python 2.7.15
```

I am new to python, not sure why its acting differently for above scenarios. Thank you.

Comment: I think `git` and `python` use different output channels for those commands. Looks like `git` uses `stdout` and `python` uses `stderr`. Nothing wrong on your side. See also https://superuser.com/questions/453598/determine-if-output-is-stdout-or-stderr

Comment: Thank you. In that case I will have to add more code to read the expected data regardless of which channel (stdout or stderr) a program may use.

Comment: Keep in mind that some programs sometimes *might* be using both channels at once but for different reasons. Should be rare.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ``subprocess``. It is entirely up to a program to decide whether to write to stdout or stderr.

Comment: BTW, using `shlex.split()` in this way is bad habit compared to doing the splitting yourself and putting `['python', '--version']` in your code. Sure, they're equivalent when your value is completely constant, but eventually you'll do something like `shlex.split('foo --arg %s' % (someStr,))` and it'll break when arguments have spaces or other syntax intended to be literal; whereas `['foo', '--arg', someStr]` is unambiguous and works the same way no matter what `someStr` contains.

Comment: @sss, ...if you just want to find the data no matter what channel it's on, you can tell `subprocess` itself to combine them both into a single string, with `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.

Comment: @charlesDuffy , thank you. I will definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: BTW, I'd argue that a literal reading of the POSIX standard would have `--version` results go to stdout, because when `program --version` is called, that version is the exact output the user asked for, vs informational or diagnostic logging. However, I completely understand why people do it the other way -- if you already have a function that writes version and usage info to stderr (for cases where the program is called with *incorrect* usage, or when it's writing real output to stdout additional to the informational messages to stderr), it's easy to just call the same thing in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code. The different result is just because the two programs are using different output channels for (at least) those commands. In particular, it looks like `git` is using `stdout`, while `python` is using `stderr`.

In order to cross check which channel one program uses, you could use the approach indicated in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/453598/determine-if-output-is-stdout-or-stderr).